# What is the cokernel of this map $\bar{1} \mapsto \bar{13}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

I am calculating the cokernel of this map: $f: \mathbb Z_9 \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{39}$ defined by $\bar{1} \mapsto \bar{13},$ I know that its image is $\{\bar{0}, \bar{13}, \bar{26}\} = 13\mathbb Z_{39} .$ Now, I know that the cokernel is defined by $\mathbb Z_{39}/\operatorname{Img} f = \mathbb Z_{39}/13\mathbb Z_{39}$ then by Lagrange theorem the number of cosets are 13. Is this correct?

**I am not sure if my application of Lagrange theorem is correct: I considered my $G = \mathbb Z_{39}$ and so its order is $39$ and my $H = 13\mathbb Z_{39}$ and its order is $39/13,$ then the cokernel is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{13}$ is that correct?**

Comment: I guess you meant it's order is 39/3 = 13. Looks good to me. Why do you think your application of Lagrange is wrong?

Comment: I meant 39/(39/13) = 13 ..... am I correct? the cokernel is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{13}$? @PhilippOtto

Comment: @PhilippOtto I think I meant the order of $H$ exactly as I wrote it.

Comment: Ah I see, you're right. But why would you write the order of $H$ is $\frac{39}{13}$? You could juste write the order of $H$ is $3$ since you already calculated $H$ and it had 3 elements. That confused me.

Comment: Oh I see @PhilippOtto you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct.  Because $\Bbb Z_{39}/\langle 13\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_{13}$, not so much by Lagrange, but by, say, the first isomorphism theorem.  That is, it is the homomorphic image of the cyclic $\Bbb Z_{39}$ (so it's cyclic) and its order is $13$.

Comment: Lagrange should work, too. The order of the cokernel of $f$ is finite so by Lagrange we have $|coker(f)| = \frac{|\mathbb{Z}_{39}|}{|im(f)|} = \frac{39}{3} = 13$. Therefore $coker(f) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{13}$.

Comment: I don't quite see how it is Lagrange, since that just says the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.  @PhilippOtto

Comment: @PhilippOtto  I guess you're right, we can go with Lagrange.  I looked it up (I was a little rusty).

Comment: Oh, the version I learned states $|G| = |H| \cdot [G:H]$ where $[G:H] = |G/H|$. In the finite case we can therefore just calculate the order of $G/H$ via the orders of $G$ and $H$.